# Converting to Maven project and adding dependencies to pom.xml automatically

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I started working on a Dynamic Web Project some time back and now I'm almost in the stage of finishing it. I have used a number of jars in my project which I have used by downloading the jars manually and then adding them to the build path in Eclipse

Now my requirement asks me to convert the project to a Maven Project which I did using Eclipse. The `pom.xml` is empty now.

Is there anyway I can automate the addition of `<dependency>` of the jars which I have used in my project to the `pom.xml` ?
Or do I have to manually search for each jar in the repo and then add its dependency in the `pom.xml`?

I have also **customized** some jars to suit my application. So I will skip adding them to the `pom.xml` obviously. But that jar has some dependencies on other jars which are used as it is; which can be obtained from the maven repo.

I could not find anything related to this on Google or Stack Overflow.

Comment: I don't see any other way than doing it manually unfortunately.

Comment: First have a dummy maven project running for a basic local repo. Rely a bit on transitive dependencies, compile for missing jar, add it and repeat. My IDE has support for repo searches.

Comment: Eclipse actually showed me an option with checkboxes that let me check all the jars it could find. But it showed the Tomcat Server jars too. Also after I checked the jars, I could not proceed further on that option.

Comment: @JoopEggen I dont' get what you are saying. Can u pls help me by explaining ?

Comment: The JavaEE API jars is what you want, they should be added as "provided", in Tomcat by the Tomcat implementation jars.

Comment: If you use a library A that uses other libraries B, C too. A compilation will find the error in a class of A. Then you add a dependency to A, and automatically you have a transitive dependency (dependency²) to B and C. That helps a bit.

Comment: I read the Tomcat jars should not be explicitly added rather they should be added by the server itself on the buildpath.

Comment: Yes , I get your point about transitive dependency. I don't mind adding the jars manually on which I have customized. But is there a way to add the non customized jars to the pom automatically ??

Comment: It is a mission nearly impossible given that dependencies are not identified by jar name but but a groupId, an artifactId and a specific version. On top of that artifacts with the same name may exist in different groups; different product, different version that was migrated, etc. Take a look at this example, which is a search for pdfbox: http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|pdfbox  Which artifact would it be if all you have is 'pdfbox.jar'?

Comment: Dead end then I guess.

Comment: You can try to search maven central by SHA-1 Checksum -  https://support.sonatype.com/entries/20870991-How-do-I-search-Central-.

Comment: @AleksandrM Nice one. But my problem is not finding the appropirate jar but it is adding all the dependencies in the pom.xml for all the jars. I have used like around 10-15 external jars, that themselves have a lot of dependencies. Adding each dependency in the pom.xml is going to take a lot of time.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. It was just FYI comment.

Comment: @ViChU that depends. If those external jars are also built with Maven, they will (hopefully) have the correct set of transitive dependencies so you won't have to add them manually

Comment: @AleksandrM Thanks, that was a good piece of info! It will surely help in finding those mysterious jars :)

Comment: @Tunaki So adding only the dependency of one jar will also include all the transitive dependencies to the pom ? I still don't get it. If am not wrong, I will have to add the transitive dependencies to the pom manually after the error throws up right ?

Comment: @ViChU The transitive dependencies will be automatically added to your buildpath so no need to explicitely add them to the pom.